# How to execute Ansible command on remote host through a jump host with set of private keys

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have 2 hosts. I am only able to ssh into one of them using another one as the jumphost. I need to create a playbook that will enable me to execute commands through a jumphost.

I was trying to follow the directions from [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#how-do-i-configure-a-jump-host-to-access-servers-that-i-have-no-direct-access-to) but I was unsuccesful. I assume had problems because it says nothing about the private keys and I need to use them to access these hosts (these host are on Openstack).

This is how my inventory looks like:

```
[app_hosts]
app ansible_host=192.168.0.4 ansible_user=ubuntu 
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=app-key.pem 
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3

[db_hosts]
db ansible_host=192.168.0.3 ansible_user=ubuntu 
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=db-key.pem

[db_hosts:vars]
ansible_ssh_common_args='ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p 
ubuntu@192.168.0.4 -i app-key.pem" ubuntu@192.168.0.3 -i db-key.pem'
```

Sadly I am getting :

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] 
*********************************************************
fatal: [db]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to 
connect to the host via ssh: channel 0: open failed: connect failed: strong text
Temporary failure in name resolution\r\nstdio forwarding 
failed\r\nssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote 
host\r\n", "unreachable": true}
```

Comment: Hi Karolina Olszewska, welcome to SO. Have you tried creating an `ssh_config` to get around all the command-line craziness? In other words, first, make it work at all, then use a `delegate_to: localhost` to write out a temporary file and feed that to all `ssh` invocations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be the complete answer, but there looks to be some confusion in the definition of 'ansible_ssh_common_args'. Try this and see if it moves you further:

```
[db_hosts:vars]
ansible_ssh_common_args='-o ProxyCommand="ssh -i app-key.pem -W %h:%p ubuntu@192.168.0.4"'
```

Changes:

- 'ansible_ssh_common_args' defines additional params to be added to the ssh command that Ansible will use, therefore you shouldn't have `ssh` at the front
- Moved -i in front the of the user@host definition, as strictly user@host should be the last component of the command
- Removed 'ubuntu@192.168.0.3 -i db-key.pem' entirely. This should not be required, as in 'ansible_ssh_common_args' you are simply defining a host to effectively tunnel connections through. So Ansible will attempt to connect to the DB host, but add the contents of 'ansible_ssh_common_args' to the SSH command it builds to enable the tunnel

Comment: It actually is a complete answer. Thank you so much !

Comment: I have two queries 
1. What If I don't want to use pem key, instead I want to include a password. 
2. Instead of ubuntu@192.168.0.4 can't I directly mention app, as it is already defined in inventory

Comment: 1) Password on the cmd line is a v bad idea, due to ease of leakage and is not supported by SSH directly, which these options are being passed to. 2) This option passes a string of params to be appended to the SSH cmd run by Ansible. SSH has no knowledge of the Ansible inventory and so does not know how to interpret 'app'. (I don't believe you can interpolate Ansible variables inside the inventory file.)